# Aligning ListView text element with TableLayout element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a `TableLayout` with two `TextView` elements representing the headings of a table, beneath the `TableLayout` I have a `ListView` each `ListView` item has a checkbox followed by two `TextView` elements representing the value for that column. So something like this

[image]

The problem is the right hand column isn't aligned with the `TableRow` second cell. Instead it appears just to the right of the end of the first `ListView` item text element. How can I acheive this?

Here's what I have

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/surveys_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/survey_name_header"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/header_cell_shape"
                android:text="@string/survey_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/survey_class_header"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/header_cell_shape"
                android:text="@string/survey_class"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/surveys_table" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

survey_list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would assume I need to modify the layout parameters in the `addView()` method of my `ListAdapter` but I'm not sure how?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.survey_list_item, parent, false);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView surveyName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView surveyClass = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //What to do here?
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: make your listview item gravity center, which is better to use

Comment: weights work **only** in LinearLayouts.

Comment: Replace `TableLayout` and `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` horizontal orientation and `android:layout_weight`